# How to avoid a redirect?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two similar wordpress websites.

> http://site.com/ and http://site.com/en/

When I try to load http://site.com/en/page1.php then it redirects automatically on to http://site.com/page1.php

Seems, I have to change rewrite rule in the htaccess.

http://site.com/ has htaccess with a content whithin:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en/.*$ en/index.php [L]
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The second one is (for http://site.com/en/):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Which rule I should write here to work that?

Comment: Please examine what each rule does before asking.

Comment: I've tried to do a lot of before therefore I'm here now. I think it wouldn't be good to write all variants I tried. For example RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$     en/$1 [L] didn't work.

Comment: How does the second rule in the first snippet interact with `/en/foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
It should be like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /en/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Select this as your accepted answer to the question. So that everyone knows that it is solved.

Comment: I will do it in a two days. The system doesn't allow to do it now